# How to change the default time of the date input field to a fixed value

Tags: javascript, angular, datetime, html-input

When we open any date input field it will show us the current date if the variable associated with the input field is null. Is there any way to configure the input field so that when we open the calendar popup instead of showing the current time it should show some other time, still keeping the value associated with the input field to be null

[image: when it is initially loaded it should not display any value]

when it is initially loaded it should not display any value

[image: When clicking on the calendar icon instead of showing current date it should be pointing some other configurable date]

When clicking on the calendar icon instead of showing current date (21/01/2022) it should be pointing some other configurable date (suppose 25/01/2022).

It might seem useless to achieve this, but i have to use this functionality in my task.

Comment: Which date picker are you using?

Comment: @RobG html input tag with type date

Comment: I think it's impossible, e.g. if there is no default date set, Safari shows the current date, it's impossible to have an empty/blank field. Default date pickers are quite implementation dependent.

Answer (score 2):

I think you could be looking for this:

from [https://developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date#value):

> You can set a default value for the input with a date inside the value attribute, like so:

```
    <input type="date" value="2017-06-01">
```

Comment: Does that satisfy "*when it is initially loaded it should not display any value*"?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want a default value for the date picker.
Then this should do:

```
<input type="date" id="start" name="trip-start"
       value="2018-07-22"
       min="2018-01-01" max="2018-12-31">
```

[source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date)